# All Objects suddenly invisible in 3D Viewer

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I was editing my model in edit mode when suddenly everything disappeared.

Things I tried:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in case I accidentally hid anything, no effect
2. Creating a new object, e.g. a cube, also invisible
3. Restarting Blender, no effect
4. Opening another scene, everything works fine
5. Opening the faulty scene on another PC, same error (clean Blender installation)
6. Switching to rendered view, here the objects **are** visible

I also noticed that if you look closely you can see a faint line along the X-axis where the objects are visible. If I move my objects around, I can notice that this line displays every object as normal where the object is intersecting it (it's hard to describe). This can be seen in the screenshot:

[image]

Is there any way I can recover my scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out: I accidentally pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> instead of <kbd>B</kbd> for *box select*, which enabled view clipping.
This way only the small portion I selected stayed visible.

To disable this, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again and the whole scene is visible again.